# If field 'a' like 'varchar' = true then concat 'varchar, 'predeterminedstring1'

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-like, concatenation

I Have a products csv file which is parsed by a program to update product records in a Mysql database.

This program has column mapping functions and the ablitiy to include SQL queries on the fields in the columns as the CSV file is parsed.

What I am trying to achieve is subcategorizing the products based on the contents of a varchar field.

To acheive subcategories the output from the SQL query must be 'parentcategory | subcategory | subcategory ', ( the pipe '|' delimiter is the required syntax for the category tree to be generated)

and I have this query in place

```
concat('default category','|',[CSV_COL(13)])
```

which gives me an output of 'default category | 'string in column 13' which is working but gives me too many sub categories under the default category.. these need parent categories to make the navigation of the site useable...

What I would like is to do a query that says

```
IF([csv_col(12)] like '*Battery*' = TRUE)  
THEN CONCAT('default category','|','batteries','|',[CSV_COL(13)])
ELSE
if([csv_col(12)] like '*power supply*' = TRUE) 
then concat('default category','|''Power Supplies','|',[CSV_COL(13)])
ELSE etc.......

ENDIF
```

Comment: Hang on, you're not storing hierarchical data in your RDBMS as a non-relational, non-normalised, delimited string are you?

Comment: What are you doing here? MySQL doesn't have array datatypes like Postgres does. Maybe you're on the wrong platform if you really want to use that structure.

Answer (score 4):

Mysql understands something like

```
SELECT IF(col LIKE '%aValue%', "ValueA", "ElseValue") FROM ...
```

You don't have to use Strings in the IF:

```
SELECT IF(col LIKE '%aValue%', Col1, Col2) FROM ...
```